# JavaScript Regex restrict _

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex

`^(?![^a-z])(?!.*\.\.)[a-z0-9._]+([a-z])$`

**Rules**

- String should start and end with [a-z]
- double . in a row is not allowed
- double _ in a row is allowed ( should be not  this is wrong)
- Allowed characters are [a-z0-9_.]

everything works as like what i want, but i cannot restrict 2 o more _ in a row
it has same restrict for . but does not work for _

This is online editor: https://regex101.com/r/XJXlpS/2

what is wrong ?

Comment: Do you have any test strings of match or not match?

Comment: @psidom There are strings in that online editor, switch to unit test tab, There are there

Comment: Your test cases do not really meet the same requirements as the ones you provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?![^a-z])(?!.*([_.])\1)[\w.]*[a-z]$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJXlpS/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?![^a-z])`: Make sure first char is a letter
- `(?!.*([_.])\1)`: Make sure we don't have repeated underscore or dot
- `[\w.]*`: Match 0+ word characters or dot
- `[a-z]`: Match a letter in the end
- `$`: End

Comment: It is not allowing, `ab__c` is a failed match in linked demo.